# How to create and use a virtual environment with PyCharm on windows?

Tags: python, windows, pycharm

I am new to PyCharm and need to run pytests within a virtual environment using PyCharm 2023.3.4 (Community Edition)  on Windows 10. I am following the documentation [HERE](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html#python_create_virtual_env) which seems to describe how to create and use a virtual environment with PyCharm. But either the documentation is outdated, or I am doing something wrong...

In the section `Create a virtual environment using the project requirements` it says to open the project folder containing the file `requirements.txt` will prompt a popup to create a virtual environment for that project - that is not true. I do not see such a popup.

Addendum: You have to create a new existing project with the `requirements.txt` file DIRECTLY in that folder. Not a project where it is in a subfolder!

Before that in the section `Create a virtualenv environment` it explains to add a Python Interpreter. I followed these somewhat complicated instructions and ended up with a `venv` folder which did not contain a `python` executable. So I am a bit lost. Should I first create the virtual environment inside a PowerShell and then "add" that to the project? Or is there some way that PyCharm creates it and installs all requirements?

I created a virtual environment locally and tried to add this as an "Python Interpreter". That did not work as I get the error "Environment location directory is not empty"...

Answer (score 1):

> ... will prompt a popup to create a virtual environment for that project - that is not true. I do not see such a popup.

You may have disabled that behavior, or there may be a glitch, or PyCharm didn't detect a `requirements.txt`.

> ended up with a `venv` folder which did not contain a python executable

On Windows, `python.exe` would be in `venv/Scripts` (and on UNIXes, `python` would be in `venv/bin`), so the folder itself not containing a Python executable is expected.

> Should I first create the virtual environment inside a PowerShell and then "add" that to the project?

That can work.

> That did not work as I get the error "Environment location directory is not empty"...

That means you tried to use "Environment: New" and pointed it at that directory; instead you need to select "Environment: Existing" in the "Add Python Interpreter" dialog and choose the `python.exe` interpreter in the virtualenv's Scripts directory.